# "Show that a single-point set {n} is closed in the digital line topology if and only if n is even."

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I have very little knowledge of set theory and proof writing. This is a problem from *Introduction to Topology: Pure and Applied* by Colin Adams and Robert Franzosa.

> DEFINITION:
> Digital line topology
>
> For each n ∈ ℤ, define
> $$  B(n) =
> \begin{cases}
> \{n\},  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
> \{n-1,n,n+1\}, & \text{if $n$ is even}
> \end{cases}
> $$

THOUGHTS

(i) For each $n \in ℤ$, $n$ is either in $\{n\}$ or $\{n − 1, n, n + 1\}$.

(ii) Let there be odd numbers $a_n$ and even numbers $b_n$ in $ℤ$.

If $a = a,$ their intersection is ${a}$.

If $a_1 ≠ a_2$, their intersection is $Ø$.

If $b = b$, their intersection is $\{b  – 1, b, b + 1\}$.

If $b_1 ≠ b_2$, their intersection is $Ø$.

If $a = b – 1$, then $B(a) ∩ B(b) = \{b – 1, b\}$, which would be contained in $\{n − 1, n, n + 1\}$.

If $a = b + 1$, then $B(a) ∩ B(b) = \{b, b + 1\}$ which would be contained in $\{n − 1, n, n + 1\}$.

If $a < b – 1$, then $\{a\} ∩ \{b\} = Ø$.

If $a > b + 1$, then $\{a\} ∩ \{b\} = Ø$.

Therefore, $\{n\}$ is open if and only if $n$ is odd.

I probably made that way more complicated than I had to, and I'm not even sure if it's right. In addition to that, I don't know how to proceed to answer the question. I know that closed sets are complements of open sets, but if I try to take the complement of a single-point odd set $\{n\}$, it's $ℤ - \{n\}$ which doesn't help me much. Anyway, as always, I appreciate any help.

Comment: The question is about $\{n\}$ is closed. And a set can be open and closed at the same time, or neither open nor closed. So the observation $\{n\}$ open iff $n$ is odd, though true, is not relevant.

Comment: Please insure that I've not changed the meaning that was intended.

Comment: What is the topology, and how is it related to the sets $B(n)$ defined in the question? Are you talking about the topology generated by the sets $B(n)$?

Comment: @bof yes, the topology generated by B(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n$ is even, say $n=2k$, then if $m \neq n$ we have two options: $m$ is even too and then $\{m-1,m,m+1\}$ is open and is disjoint from $\{n\}$, as $|n-m| \ge 2$ or $m$ is odd and $\{m\}$ is an open set disjoint from $\{n\}$ too. In both cases we see that $m \notin \overline{\{n\}}$ so $\{n\}$ is closed.

If $n$ is odd then every neighbourhood of $n+1$ contains the open set $B(n+1)= \{n,n+1,n+2\}$ so intersects $\{n\}$ and so $n+1 \in \overline{\{n\}}$ for $n$ odd, so $n$ odd implies $\{n\}$ *not* closed.

Combined with the previous gives the equivalence asked for.

Comment: Why is it the case that, if "m is odd and {m} is an open set" then it is "disjoint from {n} too"? For example, if m is 1 and n is 2, then {1}∩{1, 2, 3} = 1, doesn't it?

Comment: @Math_Student_1 $\{m\} \cap \{n\} = \emptyset$ right? I use $m \in \overline{\{n\}}$ iff every neighbourhood of $m$ intersects $\{n\}$ iff $B(m)$ intersects $\{n\}$.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm confused. If n is even then {n} is not an open set in the topology; rather, {n - 1, n, n + 1} is open. If m is even also, then it is disjoint from {n - 1, n, n + 1} for the reason you stated... why are we trying to compare m to {n} which is not an open set in the topology? I'm new to this stuff and it's frying my brain.

Comment: @Math_Student_1 I’m showing that any $m \neq n$ is not in the closure of $\{n\}$ so that that singleton is its own closure hence closed.

Comment: Would it not be sufficient, after showing that $\mathbb{Z}-\{n\}$ needs to be open, that if n is odd each neighborhood of $n+1$ would include $n$ which is a contradiction since $\mathbb{Z}-\{n\}$ does not contain $n$?